# Get HTTP Status 404 - Not Found, when the name of a dynamic web project renamed and deployed on Glassfish with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

When I rename the name of a dynamic web project with JSF v2.2 as configuration created by itself Eclipse 2019.03 then I redeploy it on glassfish v5.1 with Eclipse, 
gets HTTP Status 404 - Not Found... While it was working well before renaming project name.

web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>test1</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

There is a simple index.xhtml in /WebContent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed when a new dynamic web project with JSF as configuration has been created by itself Eclipse, if you use Glassfish as server, there will be an additional file named glassfish-web.xml in /WebContent/WEB-INFO directory.
When the name of a dynamic web project is renamed, the line below of glassfissh-web.xml file should be modified manually to new name of the project:

```
<context-root>/testProject</context-root>
```